# URI schemes supported in Windows 8 apps

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, uri, winrt-xaml, winjs

What are the URI schemes supported in Windows 8 apps? I have seen references to [ms-appx: and ms-appdata:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh781215.aspx) and some rare mentions of [ms-resource:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx) but I could not find any document that would be a list of the schemes (although I thought I have seen one in the past). I am wondering if [URL.createObjectURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453196.aspx) returns some other schemes, but I can't see a version of it for XAML apps. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh781215.aspx. Are there any other URI schemes supported in WinRT?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the [Metro js schemes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx) apply to xaml as well.

Some of those for xaml apps are listed here: [How to Load File Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322%28v=win.10%29.aspx) (for XAML apps)

`ms-resource:` for xaml apps is listed here: [ResourceLoader.GetStringForReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader.getstringforreference.aspx)

**URIs available in metro applications:**

**General form**

```
<scheme>://<domain name>/<path>
```

**Http**

```
http://www.contoso.com/images/logo.png
```

**App Package**

```
ms-appx:
ms-appx:///default.html
ms-appx-web:
```

> Content referenced via this scheme is loaded from the local package,
>   but runs with the abilities and restrictions of the web context.

**File System**

Can't be used directly.  To use, obtain an `IStorageItem` and then use `URL.createObjectURL`

```
file://
```

**App Data**

```
ms-appdata://
```

**Resources**

```
ms-resource://
```

**Dependent Packages**

```
<domain name>:
```

**URIs for [WebSockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh994399%28v=win.10%29.aspx)**

`ws:` for unencrypted and `wss:` for encrypted.  Used like this:

```
webSocket = new MessageWebSocket();
await webSocket.ConnectAsync("wss://www.example.com");
```

Answer (score 6):

There now seems to be an article on Windows Dev Center that is focused specifically on [URI schemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx).