# Check if a file exists in the project in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a WinRT Metro project which displays images based on a selected item.  However, some of the images selected will not exist.  What I want to be able to do is trap the case where they don't exist and display an alternative.

Here is my code so far:

```cs
internal string GetMyImage(string imageDescription)
{
    string myImage = string.Format("Assets/MyImages/{0}.jpg", imageDescription.Replace(" ", ""));

    // Need to check here if the above asset actually exists

    return myImage;
}
```

Example calls:

```cs
GetMyImage("First Picture");
GetMyImage("Second Picture");
```

So `Assets/MyImages/SecondPicture.jpg` exists, but `Assets/MyImages/FirstPicture.jpg` does not.

At first I thought of using the WinRT equivalent of `File.Exists()`, but there doesn't appear to be one.  Without having to go to the extent of trying to open the file and catching an error, can I simply check if either the file exists, or the file exists in the project?

Comment: It ought to be exceptional that an asset you assume exist doesn't in fact exist.  So catch the exception.

Comment: @HansPassant I would argue that he doesn't assume they exist.  He knows ahead of time that there is a possibility they don't exist.

Comment: Very agree with @mydogisbox. ExistsAsyns() has been discussed since dev preview but hasn't made it in. I still would love to hear the argumentation behind...

Comment: I was just looking at a similar [problem](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17678#313582) in my toolkit and thought it was a real bummer that the Exists method doesn't... exist. All that thing about race conditions and the method being a bad practice - what about the application assets that should never change and will virtually never be changed? I wanted to check for the files in my appx, but I could not find another option than trying to open these and catch exceptions if they are missing, which is really ugly. Maybe ResourceManager could help find them?

Comment: Found some things about the ResourceManager. You can check for files in the app package like that:
ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.ContainsKey("Files/Assets/Logo.png") or ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.ContainsKey("Files/WinRTXamlToolkit/Themes/Generic.xaml") - for files from referenced libraries. This has the added benefit of handling qualified resources - like images that might have been added with scale qualifiers in the names, but not exist at the base unqualified names - e.g. Logo.png vs. Logo.scale-100.png, Logo.scale-140.png, Logo.scale-180.png etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `GetFilesAsync` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227274.aspx) to enumerate the existing files.  This seems to make sense considering you have multiple files which might not exist.

> Gets a list of all files in the current folder and its sub-folders. Files are filtered and sorted based on the specified CommonFileQuery.

```cs
var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("Assets/MyImages/");
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
var file = files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "fileName");
if (file != null)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

**Edit:**

As @Filip Skakun pointed out, the resource manager has a resource mapping on which you can call `ContainsKey` which has the benefit of checking for qualified resources as well (i.e. localized, scaled etc).

**Edit 2:**

Windows 8.1 introduced a new method for getting files and folders:

```cs
var result = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync("fileName") as IStorageFile;
if (result != null)
    //file exists
else
    //file doesn't exist
```

Comment: Just needed the installedLocation from @Dave Bost's answer

Comment: Ah, yes.  You probably needed to use the appropriate URI scheme like from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12020163/901059  And his way of getting the path auto-prepends it.

Comment: This doesn't actually work as far as I have tried. It throws a "File not found" exception.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov then make a post about what you're having trouble with.  Clearly it worked for at least a couple other people.

Comment: Aren't file names case insensitive on Windows? Shouldn't we check the list in a case-insensitive way?

Comment: @SandRock You can't have two file names which differ only by case.  They still have case though.

Answer (score 6):

There's two ways you can handle it.

1) Catch the FileNotFoundException when trying to get the file:

```cs
 Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = 
     Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
 try
 {
     // Don't forget to decorate your method or event with async when using await
     var file = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync(fileName);
     // Exception wasn't raised, therefore the file exists
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We have the file!");
 }
 catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundEx)
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File doesn't exist. Use default.");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     // Handle unknown error
 }
```

2) as mydogisbox recommends, using LINQ. Although the method I tested is slightly different:

```cs
 Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation =
     Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
 var files = await installedLocation.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
 var file = files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == fileName);
 if (file != null)
 {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We have the file!");
 }
 else
 {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No File. Use default.");
 }
```

Comment: Just in case anyone else stumbles across this for writing WinRT apps for Windows Phone 8.1, CommonFileQuery is not currently supported.

Answer (score 2):

[`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) has an [`ImageFailed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.imagefailed.aspx) event that fires if the image can't be loaded. This would let you try to load the original image, and then react if it's not there.

Of course, this requires that you instantiate the `BitmapImage` yourself, rather than just build the `Uri`.

Answer (score 0):

Sample checking for resource availability for c++ /cx (tested with Windows Phone 8.1):

```
std::wstring resPath = L"Img/my.bmp";
std::wstring resKey = L"Files/" + resPath;
bool exists = Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::Core::ResourceManager::Current->MainResourceMap->HasKey(ref new Platform::String(resKey.c_str()));
```