# How to check if file exists in StorageFolder in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a file exists in the project in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121572/check-if-a-file-exists-in-the-project-in-winrt)

I'm using the StorageFolder and need to check if a file exists befor I read it to avoid a exception.

my code looks like this:

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(myPath);
```

the problem is, I can't find a method which checks if a file exist

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Last time I checked you had to catch an exception:
(might have changed)

Edit: this is **one** way to do it :)

Like so:

```
    static async Task<bool> DoesFileExistAsync(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this way is better:

var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await folder.TryGetItemAsync("file.txt") as IStorageFile;
 
if (file != null)
{
    // The file exists, "file" variable contains a reference to it.
}
else
{
    // The file doesn't exist.
}

Comment: Jon,

TryGetItemAsync is only available for Windows 8.1, not Windows Phone 8.1.  Your answer is valid, but not for universal apps.

Comment: Does this try to read all the file data? or it just gets the metadata?