# Copy database from installed location to local folder

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I have a database on "ms-appx:///Databases/tryout2.sqlite" (installed location). I want to copy it to the local application folder because I need to insert the data to the table in the database when the user logs in each time (if the name and email are the same, it is not insert to the database). I'm having trouble when the user first logs in, then the database can be copied to the local folder. But if the user login again, error message appears as below:
[image: error message]

App.xaml.cs:

```
    public static string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, @"Databases\tryout2.sqlite"));
            public App()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();
                this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
                if (!CheckFileExists("tryout2.sqlite").Result)
                {
                    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DB_PATH))
                    {
                        db.CreateTable<DBQUIZ>();
                        db.CreateTable<DBQUESTION>();
                        db.CreateTable<DBOPTION>();
                        db.CreateTable<DBUSER>();
                        db.CreateTable<DBRESULT>();
                    }
                }
            }

            private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
            {
                try
                {
                    var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                return false;
            }
```

DatabaseHelper.cs:

```
string DB_PATH_COPY;

        public void CreateDatabase(string DB_PATH)
        {
            if (!CheckFileExists(DB_PATH).Result)
            {
                using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection dbConn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
                {
                    dbConn.CreateTable<DBQUIZ>();
                    dbConn.CreateTable<DBQUESTION>();
                    dbConn.CreateTable<DBOPTION>();
                    dbConn.CreateTable<DBUSER>();
                    dbConn.CreateTable<DBRESULT>();
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

public async void InsertUser(DBUSER objUser)
        {
            if (!CheckFileExists(DB_PATH_COPY).Result)
            {
                StorageFile dbFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Databases/tryout2.sqlite"));
                StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                StorageFile dbFileCopy = await dbFile.CopyAsync(localFolder);
                DB_PATH_COPY = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, dbFileCopy.Path.ToString()));
            }

            using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DB_PATH_COPY))
            {
                    dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                    {
                        dbConn.Insert(objUser);
                    });
            }
        }
```

Code:

```
DatabaseHelper Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelper();//Creating object for DatabaseHelperClass.cs from ViewModel/DatabaseHelperClass.cs  
            if (emailField.Text != "" & namaField.Text != "")
            {
                Db_Helper.InsertUser(new Tryout.Models.DBUSER(emailField.Text, "", 0, namaField.Text));
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Tryout.TryoutHome1));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Nama dan Email harus diisi");//Text should not be empty  
                await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
```

How to handle it? Or is there another way to insert data to the table in the database in the installed location?

Comment: You are copying the file to to its own location? (InsertUser method).

Comment: Did you look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296994/how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-storagefolder-in-winrt)?

Comment: @brijber yes, i want copy the database from installed locaton to local package folder. Because when insert data into the database in the installed location, can not be done. The error message appears that read only. Or is there another way?

Comment: @AVK i use private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName) in my DatabaseHelper.class

Comment: You can use [`CopyAsync(IStorageFolder, String, NameCollisionOption)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.StorageFile#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_CopyAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFolder_System_String_), it creates a copy of the file in the specified folder and renames the copy. This method also specifies what to do if a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder.