# How to check file is exists

Tags: windows-runtime, c#-5.0

I am using windows runtime component C# to develop an native interface. I try to check file is exists or not with the following code:-

```
bool exists = File.Exists("D:\\Test\\test.txt");
```

I have using System and using System.IO in the beginning top of the class. But it is also not work. Can anyone help me on it?

Comment: Use a trivial google query to find help first.  "winrt file exists" shows you anything you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a file exists in the project in WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121572/check-if-a-file-exists-in-the-project-in-winrt)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public async void CheckForFile()
    {
        StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("D:\\Test\\");
        bool fileExists = await FileExists(folder, "test.txt");
    }

    public async static Task<bool> FileExists(StorageFolder folder, string name)
    {
        if (folder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("folder");
        }

        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        try
        {
            return await folder.GetFileAsync(name) != null;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```