# Can I launch another win8 app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, launch, app-launcher

Is it possible, and if so how can you launch a windows 8.1 application that has been installed on the computer from another windows 8.1 application?

I have found that for windows phone 8 you can use the following:

```
IEnumerable<Package> apps = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();
apps.First().Launch(string.Empty);
```

but I cannot find a windows 8 equivalent.

I have read about [Uri activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779670.aspx) and [Uri schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020014/uri-schemes-supported-in-windows-8-apps) but was unable to find the answer to my question.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where you open a PDF file, **letting the user select** the application they want to use. If the application is not installed, it prompts the user to download it from the store.

Notice also that I set the application to snap to the side and open the file in the other app side by side.

```
private async void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile pdf = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/irisclasson.pdf"));

    await
        Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdf,
            new LauncherOptions
            {
                PreferredApplicationDisplayName = "PDF Touch",
                PreferredApplicationPackageFamilyName = "162a2931-8ee6-4a56-9570-53282525d7a3",

                DisplayApplicationPicker = true,
                DesiredRemainingView = ViewSizePreference.UseHalf
            });
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if they have the preferred application installed, then set display application picker to false, would the preferred application automatically open? Also is this only possible through opening files? - also thanks for the help so far